# Relation between Wild Hogs and Hangover

Tags: the-hangover, wild-hogs

I recently watched 'Wild Hogs(2007)', felt there are a few similarities with 'The Hangover (2009)':

- 4 friends go on a trip, where one lies to his wife (Ed Helms and Martin Lawrence)
- Both of them have a controlling wife. (Ed Helms and Martin Lawrence)
- "He is not a doctor, he is a dentist!" is common in both the movies.
- Both stories have a weirdo (William H. Macy and Zach Galifianakis)
- 2 characters find love, well sort of (William H. Macy and Ed Helms)
- Both had a singer singing chessy songs and making gestures. (at wedding and Chilie festival).

I noticed these things and these connections flashed. Is there any (semi-)official information or external evidence that points some kind of mutual inspiration between the two movies or is this all just a big coincidence?

Comment: Welcome to the [Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com/tour). If we can maybe rephrase this more into the direction of *"Is there any information/evidence/comment on a mutual inspiration between the two movies"* this question might work. Note however, that entirely subjective discussion, as also encouraged by words like "discussion" and "share you views", does generally not fare too well on those sites.

Comment: I tried to elaborate on the question a little to give it a bit more substance. Feel free to roll it back if this doesn't fit what you originally wanted to ask. However, I think in this form it's quite an interesting question (and I never realized those apparent similarities that much before). Though, at the end of the day, I'd wager those are all pretty classic tropes/characters for those kinds of "hilarious men adventure" movies, but who knows.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion will keep in mind, and also for re-phrasing the question so nicely.

Comment: There are no shared writers, directors or actors between the two.  It was probably just Hollywood being unoriginal (as they often are) and reusing gags while hoping no one noticed.